# I have table in mysql with 20000 records. How can i retrive it faster

Tags: codeigniter

I have table in mysql with 20000 records.

How can I retrieve data faster?

I used datatable plugin for pagination and I also use codeigniter. 
It took about one minute to split records to about 4000 page

Comment: if you use the `jQuery Datatables` plugin - take a look here https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side . Btw you should read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve - because a two liner as question without any effort gets most likely closed.

Answer (score 0):

please use pagination [ci Pagination, php pagination, jquery pagination ajax(faster than others) ] if you are using bootstrap datatable its not working because datatable fetch all the data in one hit after that it breaks data on view which is time consuming you need to break the data in small groups like 20-20 or 50-50 and you need to fetch data in every hit of pagination numbers.

if you are usign ci pagination it will reload on every page hit however if you are using jquery pagination it help you to fetch data in every number hit without refreshing the pages.

please go through the following link: https://phppot.com/php/ajax-pagination-with-php/
in order to implement ajax pagination.

1. Create view and load table headers
2. add id on tbody
3. start ajax pass number want to break = 50, and page = 1
   send those value to controller and fetch data as per page.
4. in your modal you need to add limit and offset which will revised on every hit of pagination number.